# How does snapchat resize images?

Tags: ios, swift, image, swift3, compression

How does SnapChat resize images into such small file sizes while still keeping decent quality? My images are saving at around 90KB for the back camera and 45kb for the front camera. I read online that sending a single snap is around 15kb. How can I optimize images better?

Here is my code that takes a picture, resizes and optimizes it for posting:

```
// Takes a still image of a video, then resizes image while user is deciding whether to post or retake it
@IBAction func takePictureButton(_ sender: Any) {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo){
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {
            (sampleBuffer, error) in

            if sampleBuffer != nil {

                self.takePicture.isHidden = true
                self.rotate.isHidden = true
                self.back.isHidden = true
                self.save.isHidden = false
                self.retake.isHidden = false

                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)

                // Handles scaling image while user decides whether or not to post or retake
                // Scale this up for smaller images.. idk why
                let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
                let size = image.size.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.4, y: 0.4))

                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0)
                image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))

                let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

                self.imageDataToSend = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(scaledImage!, 0.4)
                self.imageToUpload = image
                self.didTakePhoto = true
                self.tempImageView.image = image
                self.tempImageView.isHidden = false
                self.captureSession?.stopRunning()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the perfect balance in resizing/compressing the image.

Fortunately, you're not the first one with this problem. [Akshay in Built.io already made some trial and error to reach the perfect balance](https://www.built.io/blog/improving-image-compression-what-we-ve-learned-from-whatsapp)

```
- (UIImage *)compressImage:(UIImage *)image{
    float actualHeight = image.size.height;
    float actualWidth = image.size.width;
    float maxHeight = 600.0;
    float maxWidth = 800.0;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth/maxHeight;
    float compressionQuality = 0.5;//50 percent compression

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
        }
        else if(imgRatio > maxRatio){
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }else{
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }
    }

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compressionQuality);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

Comment: Is there by any chance a version in Swift 3 you know of? If not that is fine, I will convert it over.

Comment: There's something in this gist, but I don't know if it's correct. https://gist.github.com/akshay1188/4749253#file-whatsapp-image-compression